# Edit and Prepare Models from Photogrammetry for Print using Blender

Tags: texturing, uv, photogrammetry

I created a photogrammetry rig and was able to generate a model using a program called 3D Zephyr. I can export it in .obj, .fbx, etc and open the model in Blender, but not much more than that. I'm looking for basic tutorials on how to apply the texture file I have to the model and remove minor blotches from the scan. So far I can find general tutorials, but nothing specific that shows me what I'm trying to do. Does anyone know of any tutorials free or paid that can help me?